# Incorrect Response when calling an action concurrenct

Tags: java, spring, jsf, concurrency

OK guys, let's go to a strange scenario !

We have JSF , Spring and Hibernate/JPA.

Assume that we have a search form and we want to search based on many inputs and the response should back to form and shows to a grid.
So, we sent some inputs to server and wait for response to show back to the user.

The problem is when :

When I open 2 browser and go to same form , and I fill my two forms with some inputs, my grids will show the incorrect result.

Incorrect result means :
form 1 : (input : **lineId=10** , result(expected) : a row which contains **lineId=10**);
form 2 : (input : **lineId=20** , result(expected) : a row which contains **lineId=20**);

But when I click my buttons on two form concurrently to call my actions of my form (Controllers) , the result is :

form 1 : (input : **lineId=10** , result: a row which contains **lineId=20**);
form 2 : (input : **lineId=20** , result: a row which contains **lineId=10**);

My forms scope is : request
My service scope is : singleton

My form has a method which called on the button action and this method sent the inputs to my services and after giving the response from my services , send it to form again for representation ( very common behaviour ).

I should say that this scenario happens in concurrent call action , and when I click my buttons unsynchronized , everything is OK .!!

What is wrong ? and what's happening ?

Comment: Could you show some of the code? It's difficult to answer you question without seeing some details.

Comment: I think the code is not important here . simple jsf , form , and service ! maybe a config problem or a silly code , I don't know. But if help , I'll put some part of code :)

Comment: I think this can only be some kind of scope issue. Did you import the correct @RequestScoped? There are two annotations with this name. One for CDI, one for JSF.

Comment: @chkal even using the *wrong* `@RequestScoped`, the bean will be by default `@RequestScoped` of the *right* type. Seems more to be a problem about the spring bean handling state, which is indeed wrong.

Comment: The code is important here to detect where may be the error. Remember that if you're working with singleton beans, the bean **must not** maintain state i.e. at most could have `static` fields and/or fields that refer to another spring singleton beans.

Comment: The interesting part is when i changed the scope of my services to prototype , nothing changed . It's really strange ! I am a code reviewer on this code and must find the problem , please let me know everything you may think possible !

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza : There are more than one hundred services and I'm searching for the possible problems and I'm searching for a service which are holding the state and is singleton! But the first work I did was changing the scope to prototype for solving such problems like maintaining state and nothing changed ...!Anyway , I'm searching for it and I'll aware you ...

Comment: OK , I found the problem !
As you guessed , the problem was related to state holding in the singleton object .
In one of the services , there was a factory builder which its work was instantiating a Line entity and **unfortunately It was a field of the singleton service** !!!!   
I remove the field and the problem solved !  
But ,  anybody knows why when I changed the scope to prototype , this problem not solved as we expected !!

Comment: And another strange thing ! If the state was the problem , so we must get the equal result in two forms , because the first request corrupt the second state and two states must be equal , isn't it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in my comment in your question and then discovered by you, the problem was due to a singleton bean having a non-singleton field that was modified by two (or more) threads at the same time.

If you're working with singleton beans, the bean must not maintain state, at most could have static fields and/or fields that refer to another spring singleton beans.

> Anybody knows why when I changed the scope to prototype , this problem not solved as we expected

Even if the top spring bean is handled as prototype, the bean that was holding the field was a singleton, so even when creating new instances of the prototype bean, all these contained a reference to the same singleton bean. If you want a spring bean to handle state, it **must** be prototype. Also, if your bean is prototype, all the beans that will use it **must** be prototype as well, otherwise Spring will create a new prototype bean **only** when creating a new instance of it (which does not happen with singleton beans).

Note that this problem is **unrelated** to JSF and completely related to Spring configuration.